Linker Error LNK2019: Unresolved External Symbol 'main' in Custom C++ Framework Application (Nexus)
I am developing a C++ application using a custom framework called Nexus. While building my Sandbox project, which serves as a client application, I encounter a linker error that prevents successful compilation.
Error Message:
MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)
D:\Cpp\..Engine\bin\Debug-x64\SandBox\SandBox.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
Done building project "SandBox.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

Project Structure
I have two projects in my solution:

Nexus (DLL Project):

Files Included:

Core.h
Application.h
Application.cpp (defines the Application class)


Settings:

Project type: Dynamic-Link Library (DLL)
Preprocessor Definitions: NX_BUILD_DLL, NX_PLATFORM_WINDOWS




Sandbox (Application Project):

Files Included:

Sandbox.cpp (implements the client application)
Includes headers from the Nexus framework (Core.h, Application.h, EntryPoint.h)


Settings:

Project type: Application (.exe)
Subsystem: Console
Preprocessor Definitions: NX_PLATFORM_WINDOWS





Source Code
Here are the relevant parts of my code:
Core.h
#pragma once

#ifdef NX_PLATFORM_WINDOWS
    #ifdef NX_BUILD_DLL
        #define NEXUS_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define NEXUS_API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif // NX_BUILD_DLL
#else
    #error NEXUS only supports Windows!
#endif // NX_PLATFORM_WINDOWS

Application.h
#pragma once
#include "Core.h" 

namespace Nexus {
    class NEXUS_API Application
    {
    public:
        Application();
        virtual ~Application();

        void Run();
    };
    Application* CreateApplication(); // to be defined in client
}

EntryPoint.h
#pragma once

#ifdef NX_PLATFORM_WINDOWS

extern Nexus::Application* Nexus::CreateApplication();

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto app = Nexus::CreateApplication();
    app->Run();
    delete app;
}

#endif // NX_PLATFORM_WINDOWS

Nexus.h
#pragma once

// For use by Nexus application
#include "Nexus/Application.h"
#include "Nexus/EntryPoint.h"

Sandbox.cpp
#include <Nexus.h>

class Sandbox : public Nexus::Application
{
public:
    Sandbox() {
        // Initialization code for Sandbox
    }

    ~Sandbox() {
        // Cleanup code for Sandbox
    }
};

Nexus::Application* Nexus::CreateApplication() {
    return new Sandbox();
}

Application.cpp
#include "Application.h"

namespace Nexus {
    Application::Application() {}

    Application::~Application() {}

    void Application::Run() {
        while (true);
    }
}

Project Configuration:

The Sandbox project is set as an Application (.exe).
The Subsystem is configured as Console.
Preprocessor definitions include NX_PLATFORM_WINDOWS.

Additional Information:

The CreateApplication function is defined correctly in Sandbox.cpp.
I verified that the NEXUS_API macro is applied properly.
The Nexus project builds without issues.
I have cleaned and rebuilt the solution multiple times, but the error persists.
File Structure



Which cpp files have been added to your project? I would guess that Sandbox.cpp is missing.

BTW defining main is a header file is really weird. Why did you do that? Are you following some boiler plate sample code?

@john I was following a tutorial from youtube but its 6-7 yrs old,

@john there are 2 projects, Nexus which is .dll and the other is Sandboc .exe

"following a tutorial from youtube" perhaps that's the problem.

So I then you need to clarify which cpp files and which settings belong to which projects. The error is somewhere in these details so you need to describe them precisely

@john Just added the file structure pls check

The file structure is not the issue. The issue is 1) which cpp files belong to which projects? 2) Which project settings apply to which projects? By project settings I mean project type, preprocessor defintions etc etc.

In your initial description you implied that there was only one project, now we learn that there are two. This matters and needs to be clarified.

@john 1)Nexus .dll - Core.cpp , Application.cpp,
2)Sandbox .exe Sandbox.cpp, also includes/imports nexus.h

@Ainz OK, previous comment (now deleted) had all the information. You really should put that comment in the main body of the question.

So, your Nexus project is a DLL (does not need main), and your Sandbox project is an EXE (needs main), but your main seems to be defined in the header file (why?) of the DLL project and only gets built with certain pre-processor definitions (and I assume it is not included in the EXE project). I'd say: scrap off this mess, and start with a simple EXE project that builds, then add a DLL project that builds, and then make them work together. I assume the EXE just uses methods defined in the DLL, do the DLL will also need an entry point. Bottom line: you need to understand what you are doing.

@Ainz I can't immediately see the error. My suggestion to help investigate this issue is to move main from the header file to Sandbox.cpp. See what difference that makes. But I agree with the previous comment, your set up is very strange and not necessary for any reason I can see. Might be best to just start again.

I'll give it another try. I was following a tutorial that suggested defining main in EntryPoint.h to allow the engine to manage the application's functionality.
Given that context, are there specific changes you recommend I make to the structure? Should I keep the main in EntryPoint.h, or would it be better to move it directly into the Sandbox project?

@Ainz I can't comment on Nexus, I don't know anything about it. As I said I would suggest moving main to sandbox.cpp as an investigation. Try that, see what happens, and use that information as a clue to the real problem. Once you have found out what the real problem is you can then decide what action to take. As the previous commentator said, unfortunately there is no alternative to understanding what you are doing.

@john yes the main is real problem, when moved to sandbox there was no issue

@Ainz That would imply to me that when you say #include <nexus.h> you are not including the file you think you are, or it would imply that you have not defined NX_PLATFORM_WINDOWS (despite what you said). Here's another suggestion, put main back into entrypoint.h but this time add a deliberate error in the code, something that would make the compiler emit an error message (for example change delete app; to delete app2; that should produce an undeclared variable error message). Now try to rebuild, do you see the error message?

@Ainz Now I'm guessing that you will not see the error message, and that implies that for some reason your project is not compiling main when it is located in EntryPoint.h. So that gives you something more to investigate.

@Ainz Assuming all that works out the next thing I would try is to remove #ifdef NX_PLATFORM_WINDOWS and #endif // NX_PLATFORM_WINDOWS from EntryPoint.h, see if that fixes the problem. And so on, and so on. This is how you fix programming bugs.
